# How to scale my Ec2 server vertically based on the CPU usage of Batch process in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, batch-processing, autoscaling

I have a Batch Java application that is deployed on AWS EC2 server. The batch process is not same at all times. There will be a bulk file with million of records or sometimes with small CSV files with 100 records. This job will trigger every time a file upload to the directory.

The problem is that my EC2 is not processing the bulk files sometimes due to high CPU usage and it got a timeout. Since it's a Batch process, Auto Scaling is not a solution for this. Also, I know vertical scaling is not possible (Need to stop/start) for this kind of jobs.

Do we have any other AWS solution for this scenario?

Comment: Can't you increase the timeout? Creating a more powerful instance is likely to reduce the time it takes to process the batch, but it will increase your bill.

Comment: Yes.. I am searching for a cost-effective way. So I asked for Vertical scaling or any other solutions?